# How do I split these strings into arrays of strings?

Tags: python

I have several strings with phrases or words separated by multiple spaces.

```
c1 = "St. Louis       12             Cardinals"
c2 = "Boston          16             Red Sox"
c3 = "New York        13             Yankees"
```

How do I write a function perhaps using the python `split(" ")` function to separate each line into an array of strings? For instance, c1 would go to `['St. Louis', '12', 'Cardinals']`.

Calling `split(" ")` and then trimming the component entities won't work because some entities such as St. Louis or Red Sox have spaces in them.

However, I do know that  all entities are at least 2 spaces apart and that no entity has 2 spaces within it. By the way, I actually have around 100 cities to deal with, not 3. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, what is a regex split?

Comment: Are the values actually lined up like this? Are those really spaces in between, or tabs?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. They're all spaces - no tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without regular expressions:

```
c1 = "St. Louis       12             Cardinals"
words = [w.strip() for w in c1.split('  ') if w]
# words == ['St. Louis', '12', 'Cardinals']
```

Comment: Thanks! This does the job without loading a module.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re
re.split(r' {2,}', c1)
re.split(r' {2,}', c2)
re.split(r' {2,}', c3)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, how does this work? Why is there a comma after the 2?

Comment: This is an example of [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), otherwise known as regex (I suggest you take a look!). The expression says what we are splitting around: ` {2,}` means "two or more spaces". If we wrote ` {2,5}`, it would mean 2 to 5 spaces- the comma leaves it open ended.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with regular expressions:

```
import re

blahRegex = re.compile(r'(.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*?)')

for line in open('filename','ro').readlines():
    m = blahRegex.match(line)
    if m is not None:
         city = m.group(1)
         rank = m.group(2)
         team = m.group(3)
```

There's a lot of ways to skin that cat, you could use `named groups`, or make your regular expression tighter.. But, this should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split)

```
>>> re.split('\s{2,}','St. Louis       12             Cardinals')
['St. Louis', '12', 'Cardinals']
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that content is fixed-width.  If that is always the case and assuming those are spaces and not tabs, then you can always reverse it using slices:

```
split_fields = lambda s: [s[:16].strip(), s[16:31:].strip(), s[31:].strip()]
```

or:

```
def split_fields(s):
    return [s[:16].strip(), s[16:31:].strip(), s[31:].strip()]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> split_fields(c1)
['St. Louis', '12', 'Cardinals']
>>> split_fields(c2)
['Boston', '16', 'Red Sox']
>>> split_fields(c3)
['New York', '13', 'Yankees']
```